# How can I make console.group output to debug or info instead of log?

Tags: javascript, browser, console.log

I try to keep `console.log` clean so I use `console.debug` and `console.info` when possible but how can I make it so that `console.group` logs to `info` or `debug`.  It keeps putting an empty group in `log`.  I don't see any option to change it to output somewhere else.

Comment: Can you show me your code? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Using_groups_in_the_console It should work as expected

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell, it's not specifically meant to work that way according to the specification (which is more concerned with interactivity and is light on other details):

https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#grouping

In practice, a group can contain different types of output (so for instance, info and debug) so I think the intention here is to make groups useful to specific actions (so group all this console output for this function) so having a group header that is always visible makes some sense. Not sure if that is helpful.

Comment: I just hit exactly this (wanting a console group which only contains warnings to be hidden when warnings are hidden). In fact, that link you posted contains the spec which says the console `group()` and `groupCollapsed()` functions are [specified to use the 'log' level of severity](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#loglevel-severity). I can't see this being possible to change without explicit browser support.